# Youtube Data API v3 always give me error

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am trying to make a task that will allow user to upload video to youtube

I am trying to make this app work : https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android

but it always gives me the following error

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "usageLimits",
      "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
      "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
      "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (YouTube Data API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
}
```

although I have already add android API key with Auth2.0 and without it but nothing is working.

Can Any one help please or at least give me a simple example to upload youtube video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the example work with me after I enable the youtube service on my google account

using the following link: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list

I found the previous link on the following website : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/888694/Youtube-Data-API-v-on-Android-Introduction